# JPA No Persistence provider for EntityManager

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I know there are some other questions on this subject, but none of the answers worked.
I am new to JPA and I am using EclipseLink as implementation and Eclipse as IDE.
This is my `persistence.xml` (it is in META-INF folder):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
            version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">

    <persistence-unit name="DBService" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

        <class>com.maze.model.EventModel</class>
        <class>com.maze.model.StoryModel</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mazedb;create=true" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="pass" />

            <!-- EclipseLink should create the database schema automatically -->
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

and here I am trying to get an EntityManagerFactory

```
private EntityManagerFactory emf;
emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("DBService");
```

At runtime, I get this error:
`javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named DBService`

I have followed the steps from tutorials, but no results...

**Edit:** I have also added into WEB-INF/lib these jars: `eclipselink.jar; javax.persistence_2.0.3.v201010191057.jar; mysql-connector-java-5.1.17-bin.jar`, added JPA to the `Project Facets` but no have seen no results yet...

Comment: How do you package your application. It's a standalone app or *.war that you run in application server? What is the **exact location** of your `persistence.xml` in your directory structure?

Comment: @PiotrNowicki I am using Eclipse IDE for Java EE. I have created a Dynamic Web Project and this folder is automatically created.

Comment: So if you're using *.war - is your `persistence.xml` in `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml`?

Comment: Yes, now I am sure it is where it should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put your persistence.xml in the META-INF directory of your war file. Also, put a copy in your lib directory and the classes directory.

I am using eclipselink at work, using a standalone jar package that contains my entity classes, a MET-INF directory with the persistence.xml and it works fine.

Probably you need to make a jar file containing the entity classes, plus a MET-INF/persistence.xml, and add this jar file to your lib directory, alongside the eclipselink.jar.

The other thing to check is the RESOURCE-LOCAL, you should use this if you are using JPA in a web-app, with no entity beans components, or in a standalone application.

Comment: I have added JPA to the Project Facets, so now it should be reognized. I even have a META-INF folder in src.

Comment: what web-container are you using tomcat?

Comment: OK, I don't know glassfish, but its probably a jakarta tomcat under the hood, so thats OK. I would advise you take things back to basics.

Comment: OK, I don't know glassfish, but its probably a jakarta tomcat under the hood, so thats OK. I would advise you take things back to basics. Try a single jar file with one Entity class, and the META-INF/persistence.xml, remove the other 'sprinklings' of persistence.xml, when you make your jar file, add this to your WEB-INF/lib directory, and see if it works, you should also makesure the WEB-INF/lib folder also contains the java JPA jar file you are rellying on, it should be part of the container lib, but just add it here to ensure its being picked up.

Comment: Yes, you were right, it was a problem with the position of `persistence.xml` and when I got it right, there was a naming problem(lack of attention). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You must put your persistence.xml in the META-INF and write persistence.xml with Lowercase letter.

I think you wrote first letter or some letter with Capital letter and i have this error too.
You must write exactly like this: ***persistence.xml***